# How can I manually replicate Manjaro Setup's automatic full-system encryption setup?

Tags: grub, manjaro, whole-drive-encryption

When I install Manjaro (16.10.3) from the LiveCD using the erase drive + encrypted option, it seems to create a setup like the following:

- Encrypted `/dev/sda1` holding `/` and encrypted `/dev/sda2` used as swap
- Unknown process prompts for decryption passphrase at boot
- Entering passphrase brings up GRUB menu, from which Manjaro can be booted

How is this accomplished? On the Arch wiki's "encrypted boot" section, I can only find a description for UEFI systems (my computer is BIOS only). That one also involves creating a separate (encrypted) `/boot` partition, which Manjaro does not create.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Grub is basically taking care of it. Notice that although you are prompted for the passphrase before the Grub menu, it is right *after* the "Welcome to Grub" message.

Take a look inside the `grub.cfg` file at the following entries:

```
insmod cryptodisk
insmod luks
insmod gcry_rijndael
insmod gcry_sha256
...
cryptomount -u [encrypted container UUID]
set root='cryptouuid/[encrypted container UUID]
...
search ... --hint='cryptouuid/[encrypted container UUID]
```

After Grub, there are some obviously important settings in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf:

```
FILES="/crypto_keyfile.bin"  
HOOKS="[nothing out of the ordinary except `encrypt`]"
```

It's a recent feature of their Calamares installer that has provided this functionality on install.

Also, take a look at [this](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Installation_to_SSD_(quick_guide)) if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm confused by this. How is GRUB loaded before decryption when it's on `/boot` that is part of the encrypted fs?

Comment: At some point, the installer program ran the command `grub-install`, which installed it to the master boot record of the hard drive.  My guess is that grub can detect an encrypted drive/partition from there then opens the grub.cfg that it needs to finish the job, provide a menu etc., afterwords.  The MBR is where the partition table lives, too.  I'm pretty sure of the gist of this though I don't claim to understand every detail of the boot process.